# is it safe to key in your password in an iphone?

Tags: iphone, security, password, apple-id

I've got 2 questions regarding password security and IPhone

If say I access the internet and key in my gmail password. Exactly how "safe" is this action?

What about if i install an app and key in my apple id password. How "safe" is this action?

(Btw I'm using IPhone 4 if its useful to the question..)

Comment: It's as safe as entering your password on a computer, which is to say, not very. There are attacks that can obtain information even through HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you're on encrypted WiFi, unencrypted WiFi, 3G, etc. if the site's title has a lock next to it, you can be sure that your password cannot be captured by anyone snooping the traffic. The lock means that you and the website are using a secure, encrypted connection.

Keep in mind however, that if after you log into the site and the lock no longer appears, you're vulnerable to anyone running a copy of Firefox with Firesheep installed. They won't get your password but will essentially be able to be logged in as you.

For sites that do not keep a secure connection (a lock in the title bar) after logging in you should avoid using them on unencrypted WiFi. As far as I know, Gmail uses a secure connection all of the time.

When you enter your password for App Store purchases, even though there isn't any real indication, your phone is establishing a secure connection between it and Apple. It's very safe.

[image: SSL icon]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are connected to the internet. Lets say you are on your own wi-fi network. The iPhone is as safe as any other device you use to connect to Gmail. However if you are using a public network it is a different story. Especially, any traffic sends through http protocol can be easily read by a hacker. AFAIK Gmail uses https which makes it relatively safe even on a public wi-fi network. If you use 3g network it should be OK. Although it is not really difficult to set up a 3g transmeter for less than $1500 ;)